# nodejs: how do I record video of a running process when it is minimized or behind other apps on windows?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to record a video of a running application on my windows machine even when it is not displayed on the screen like when it is minimized or behind other applications.

How can I accomplish this in Node.js? Most packages seem to require that application is visible on the screen as they capture a specific region. I need to record the video regardless.

```
const recordScreen = require('record-screen')

const recording = recordScreen('/tmp/test.mp4', {
  resolution: '1440x900' // Display resolution
})

recording.promise
  .then(result => {
    // Screen recording is done
    process.stdout.write(result.stdout)
    process.stderr.write(result.stderr)
  })
  .catch(error => {
    // Screen recording has failed
    console.error(error)
  })

// As an example, stop the screen recording after 5 seconds:
setTimeout(() => recording.stop(), 5000)
```

Comment: can it record a pid? if so, u have ur solution, other wise... dang i never even thought of doing this LOL

Comment: @TheBombSquad what do you mean?

Comment: process id, lots of things are running in the background, but have a process id

Comment: anyway i'll watch this question to see what the answer looks like

Comment: @TheBombSquad not sure I'm on windows 10

Comment: ite go in cmd and type tasklist

Comment: scroll up to see the headings for each of the data parts in the table, u would see a heading looking like PID

Comment: @TheBombSquad okay what do i with this pid now